# Make a table with different dimensions with divs

Tags: html, css

I want to display 5 rating elements on DLE in 4 cells. This is what I have right now:

```
<table width=100%>
<tr>    
   <td width=10%>
   <div class="custom-data"> Score IMDB</div>
   </td>
   <td>
        <div class="custom-data">Score Users</div>
        <div class="custom-data">Stars</div>
   </td>  
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>IMDB</td>
   <td>Users</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

This should look like

```
Score IMDB | Score Users *****
   IMDB    |   Users
```

I have width defined in the first column. I want to make a border in the middle to separate the scores, but I can't do it with the table right?

The `ul li` tags mess up the stars. My only way is to do a `div`.

Can you help me with the code to make this structure?

Comment: "the ul li tags"... **WHAT** `ul li` tags?

Comment: For lists @MarcB <ul> <li>

Comment: @PedroLino He means where are the `ul` `li` tags in your code.

Comment: So the width of the content is dynamic?

Comment: @user2989408 oh sorry. What i mean is that i have tried building it with that tags and messed up the stars.

Comment: @DanielLisik Only in the first collum, because if i have the same size for the two collums, the second one will be far away from the first one, i just want them to align side by side as i showed in the example.

Comment: @PedroLino that problem can be resolved by having one width specified for the left column and another for the right. I mean, since you hade the text in the center of the column in the description I thought you wanted this effect. Without specified width I don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">Score IMDB</div><div class="right">Score Users *****</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="left">IMDB</div><div class="right">Users</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right { display:inline-block; margin:5px 0; }
.left { border-right:1px solid #000; width:90px; padding:4px; }
.right { padding:4px 4px 4px 10px; }
```

The 'magic' here really lies in `display:inline-block`, which allows us to put divs next to each other.
Hope this helps!

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/Eaxvv/2/)

## Note

Since you wanted the right second column to have dynamic width, the effect of centered text (like you have in the description of what you wanted), will not be visible on the right column. If you still wish that effect on the left column, add this code to *.left*:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: For some reason, "Users" pops under "IMDB". :/

Comment: On the demo? Strange.. works fine to me (unless you resize the result window to a very small width, but in that case nothing could preserve the 'table' the way you wanted unless you would have responsive css).

Comment: No, not the Demo, that is fine. It's fine if i change it to my code too actually. The problem is with my website... it's strange that the Scores are ok, but the IMDB and User isn't...

Comment: Do you perhaps have other css for the same class names as I used? In that case they could have interfered and made the result strange.

Comment: You could also take a look through developer toolbar (if you use chrome, right-click on an element and choose "Inspect element" or somehting similar), and see what causes this.

Comment: No, that was the first thing i checked. I even changed the names. I am checking the structure in "inspect element" mode on firefox, and it's all messed up... :S didn't stack had a chat? I could send you the link to show you

Comment: Sure, let's take it at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign, ok?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46547/discussion-between-pedro-lino-and-daniel-lisik)